# What would a Hindu be willing to die for?

Tags: death

What things would a Hindu be willing to die for? Are there any examples of martyrdom occurring in Scriptures, or any reasons a Hindu would be willing to die?

Comment: Can you add some context to your question? Some examples perhaps. Are you specifically looking for examples from Hindu scriptures where people have given up lives for a good cause?

Comment: [Read the above comment from SV] Or is it that you want to know what the present day Hindu (generalized) would do?

Comment: @Narayanan Yes, it is that I would like to know what the present day Hindu (generalized) would do. As in: _Would they be willing to die to save other people's lives?_ and a multitude of other things.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Hindu* context, a *khastriya* fights (Although, there have been exceptions too).

To answer the title question:

> What would a Hindu be willing to die for?

If we look at the *Hindu* leaders, just a few centuries back, or look at our soldiers, we see a great spirit of sacrifice for the nation.

You can read about *Maharana Pratap*, who is venered for his courage even though he lost in the *[Battle for Haldighati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maharana_Pratap#Battle_of_Haldighati)*.

This famous [poem](http://kaavyaalaya.org/jhansi.shtml) enunciates the *Shaurya* of *Jhansi Ki Rani* who faught valianty against the *British* and died.

*[Chhatrapati Shivaji Maharaj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shivaji)*, was a *Hindu* leader most famous for his courage and spirit of sacrifice. He fought under the guidance of his Guru *[Samartha Ramdas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samarth_Ramdas)* (composer of the *Advaitin Vedanta* text *[Dasbodh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dasbodh)*).

These are only a few examples. There are so many more that can be given.

Comment: These seem to be examples of "what would a **warrior** be willing to die for": all of your examples use the words "battle" or "fought". You haven't included any specific reasons except "spirit of sacrifice for the nation", and it isn't really clear that you are answering *this* question. I didn't downvote, I'm just letting you know. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @wizzwizz4:  I answered in context of the varna system. The warriors or khsatriyas were Hindu, their 'job' is to fight, then the brahmins provide guidance as is enunciated in the case of Shivaji. I agree that it does not answer 'in general' why a Hindu be willing to die. I also assume that it cannot be answered in a general sense.